# Is it ok to remove NGons with triangulation in order to import a model in a game engine?

Tags: modeling, game-engine, unity, geometry

Sometimes the model ends up having a very messy geometry, is it a problem in games engines such as Unity?

Comment: It is ok (more or less) unless it's not visible that triangulation was done. If Ngon wasn't planar (flat) most likely there will be visible edges of resulting tris.

Comment: You can also use quads, which deform better in many cases.

Comment: When the NGon is not flat it should not be an NGon anyway. The same belongs to quads. The assumption is they are flat.

Comment: related reading -- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/how-to-make-all-quads-or-ngons-on-your-mesh-planar-2d

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The potential problem you can run into with n-gons is that different programs break them up into triangles in different ways. Depending on how you've configured your mesh's shading, this can alter the way smooth shading is averaged across the face.

If your n-gons are flat-shaded and planar, you shouldn't encounter problems. If you're using smooth shading, or weighted normals, and are relying on a normal map to get your final shading result, it can potentially look different in different programs.

If you bake you bake your normal map in a program that triangulates ngons one way, and then move it into a program that does it a different way, you will get a bad result.

Generally you can't go wrong triangulating your mesh before baking normals. It removes the potential for error.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Game engines like Unity automatically triangulate faces that have more than 3 vertices on a face.

You can either do nothing or triangulate everything yourself with modifier or ALT+F if you think it looks better. It's completely fine.