# Shading artifacts / Tricky modelling situation

Tags: modeling, mesh, shaders, artifacts

I hope someone can help me out with this.

I'm modelling a moka pot, similar to this one:

[image: Moka pot]

This is what my mesh looks like in the snout area:

[image: Fig. 1]

[image: Fig. 2]

[image: Fig. 3]

As shown in Fig. 3, I marked the planes around the front of the snout as smooth, to get a nice rounded edge. However, in rendered view I get weird artifacts, such as can be seen here:

[image: Fig. 4]

[image: Fig. 5]

Does anyone know why I'm getting these weird results? Nothing I do seems to help.

Here's the .blend file:

[coffee.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51527)

Comment: Might be *Planar* issue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/how-to-make-all-quads-or-ngons-on-your-mesh-planar-2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simplify your topology. Something simple is more controlable.
[image: topo compare]
[image]