# Blender transforming quads to tris

Tags: cycles-render-engine, faces

So, I started creating a tank, and when I checked the rendered mode, I found that I have tris instead of quads.

No modifiers applied, no anything.

Anyone please help ?

tris:
[image]

edit mode (quads):
[image]

Comment: All geometry is triangulated during render by default. See here how to avoid triangulated look: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/how-to-make-all-quads-or-ngons-on-your-mesh-planar-2d

Comment: if  you use images make sure you upload them in your post edit. Hot linking doesn't ensure your images stay up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by the fact your vertices don't align well on the plane of the quad. And the render engine doesn't magically create new data and uses the quad as is ( which is basically just 2 triangles anyways ). If you look at the lower vertex of the quad you can see it's pointing a bit inwards. If you were to divide a quad into 2 triangles you'd see an edge going trough the middle and that's exactly what happens here.

You might want to consider adding more faces to accommodate for slope or change your shape a bit to make the quads vertices more aligned. Or use smooth shading and the normals of the face are interpolated to bend between faces.

Technically @Ween 's answers should work as it aligns the vertices to be on the same plane preventing the triangle bend of the quad.

Answer (score -1):

You can try select all faces and press <kbd>Space</kbd> and input *Make Planar Faces* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: no, that didnt help, still have tris. Let me post some pictures.

Comment: It focused on biggest faces, and made them planar, but it didnt work perfectly. There are still other left. Tried it couple of times, and it got a little better, but not solved perfectly.