# Is there a way to highlight bent faces when modeling?

Tags: modeling, faces, geometry, topology

Say you create a default plane, go into edit mode, and move one of its corners on the Z-axis like so:

[image]

This bends the plane's face, making it no longer perfectly flat. This can be solved by moving the face's corners or cutting the face into tris. Is there any way to highlight these bent faces so that I know which ones to fix, similar to the Face Orientation overlay?

**For my specific project I do need to correct non-planar faces so just ignoring them is not an option so unlock the question please. Thanks.**

Comment: you don't have to worry about non-planar faces as explained here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56764/142292

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Uhhh, no, actually, for my specific project I do need to correct non-planar faces. Please unlock the question.

Comment: a moderator closed your question because the moderator believes there are already answers for your question in the link they provided. this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/how-to-make-all-quads-or-ngons-on-your-mesh-planar-2d

Comment: The linked question presents multiple solutions to make faces planar, not just ignore them. If you feel your question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, *Edit* your post, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: I have to agree with the original poster.  The 'duplicate' answers 'how to fix' but this question asks 'how to find' and as far as I can tell, neither of the answers on the prior question describe how to find.  I vote to reopen.

Comment: @MartyFouts it says "*This post was edited and submitted for review 3 days ago.*" Do you know how many people there are that review these posts for reopen state?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie one moderator or three non-moderator votes I think.

Comment: Does the suggested [mesh analysis](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html#distortion) option not address your issue?

Comment: @RobertGützkow Well I tried replying to you but these cowards around here didn't like it and CENSORED me again so I guess you will just have to go look up your answer.